# extend matrix of time elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, time

I've got 1xn matrix called time that I imported from a csv file. Is there any way to extend this matrix by following the time pattern (so that the days per month work)? For example, if I start with.

```
time = 

    '"2013-05-01"'
    '"2013-05-02"'
    '"2013-05-03"'
    '"2013-05-04"'
    '"2013-05-05"'
```

And somehow add 5 observations, my matrix becomes:

```
time = 

    '"2013-05-01"'
    '"2013-05-02"'
    '"2013-05-03"'
    '"2013-05-04"'
    '"2013-05-05"'
    '"2013-05-06"'
    '"2013-05-07"'
    '"2013-05-08"'
    '"2013-05-09"'
    '"2013-05-10"'
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If `time` is a char matrix:

   ```
   N = 5; %// how many dates to add
   lastdate = datenum(strrep(time(end,:),'"',''),29); %// last available date
   time = [time; [repmat('"',N,1) datestr(lastdate+(1:N),29) repmat('"',N,1)] ];
   ```
2. If `time` is a cell array, just replace last line by

   ```
   time = [time; mat2cell([repmat('"',N,1) datestr(lastdate+(1:N),29) repmat('"',N,1)],ones(1,N)) ];
   ```

This works by reading the last string date, converting to numerical date with [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), generating `N` new consecutive dates, and then converting back to string with [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html). The double quotes are dealt with separately.

Example:

```
>>time = ['"2013-05-04"'; '"2013-05-05"']

time =

"2013-05-04"
"2013-05-05"
```

gives

```
>> N = 5; %// how many dates to add
lastdate = datenum(strrep(time(end,:),'"',''),29); %// last available date
time = [time; [repmat('"',N,1) datestr(lastdate+(1:N),29) repmat('"',N,1)] ]

time =

"2013-05-04"
"2013-05-05"
"2013-05-06"
"2013-05-07"
"2013-05-08"
"2013-05-09"
"2013-05-10"
```

Comment: @JoeDanger Glad it worked. Note that in your case, since all strings have the same width, you could work with a matrix instead of a cell array. It's more efficient in terms of memory, and probably in terms of time as well

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `time` is a cell array here:

```
t = cell2mat(time);
n = 5;
t = datenum(t,'"yyyy-mm-dd"'); % using custom format
tdiff = t(end)-t(end-1); % assuming 
l = length(t);

newtime = zeros(l+n,1);
newtime(1:l)=t;
newtime(l+1:end) = (t(end)+tdiff):tdiff:(t(end)+tdiff*n);
```

You can use `datestr` to convert back to the date format of your choice.

Comment: +1 I didn't know you coud use a custom format in `datenum`. It simplifies things a lot

Comment: I deal with too many {bleep} who use strange and unnatural date formatting.